# How to pass value from controller to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes, :as => :notable,  :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :work_times, :dependent => :destroy
end

class WorkTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
end


class NotesController < ApplicationController


      end
    end
####
```

Any help please??

Comment: It looks like your "something like" is the right answer.  What's the problem with it?

Comment: This is what I get undefined method `work_time' for #<Task:0x1051afcb0>. I am getting date but final line of code * work_time.start_time == time is giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the relationship is a `has_many` you will need to work with a particular time, not the aggregate:

```
work_time = @task.work_times.last
work_time.start_time = Time.now
work_time.save!
```

In this case the last WorkTime record is selected and manipulated. Maybe you want to use the first, or select it with a condition:

```
work_time = @task.work_times.where(:active => true).first
```

There's a lot of ways to select the correct record to manipulate, but your question is somewhat vague.

If you're looking to create a new entry instead of modifying one, you might want to do this:

```
@task.work_times.create(:start_time => Time.now)
```

This is just exercising the ActiveRecord model relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You would simply get the object and just change its value like :

```
user = User.first
user.username = 'changed_name'
user.save # and save it if you want
```

But, this is actually code that belongs to a model and should be wrapped by a model method.

Comment: Soory I am new to Ruby Rails I dont understand, What exactly you are asking me to do?? My code is working and i am able to get a date. All I need to pass that date in start_time attribute in work_time model

Comment: The WorkTime model on its own, is a class. The start_time is an attribute of a particular object of that class. So, if you have an object like 'work_time = WorkTime.find(2)', you can do work_time.start_time on that object, in order to change the value. In short, you first have to create an object of type WorkTime and then you can set any value.

Comment: Yeah I got it, but workTime is also a pending issue for me, I want to populate task_id in work_times table on creating a task which generate on creating a registrar. Right now my work_times table is empty

Comment: if a work_time has a task, you can simply do work_time.task.create() or just work_item << task, where task in a particular task to be created.

Comment: In my WorkTime is just model where I want to store task_id and start_time and ed_time. So I can calculate total time taken on each tasks

Comment: yes, that is ok. I would advice you to take a look at the associations : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to by a few of the other answers, you need an object of type WorkTime to pass the value to.

From the code you've posted it doesn't look like you've got such an instance. You can either find one (WorkTime.find.. ) or create a new one (WorkTime.new..)

It looks like you have an instance of a note (@note), though I'm not sure where that came from.. you might be able to fetch appropriate WorkTime objects using:

```
@note.task.work_times
```

or the first of these with:

```
@note.task.work_times.first
```